Why kinetically controlled enolate is not formed?
The synthesis of Gymnamitrol by Steven C. Welch started with this reaction in this publication

This is rather odd as I suppose the enolate formation should be thermodynamically stable since LDA is a bulky base, which should deprotonate the opposite acidic hydrogen. Why is it different in this case?

I too got a bunch of such examples: 2-Methylcyclohexanone with LDA at $-78^\circ$ comprises of 78% of the rather unstable enolate. $\ce{Ph3CLi}$ under DME comprises of 90% of the same enolate, 93% with $\ce{tBuOK}$

The "unstable enolate" that you mention is kinetically favored one, right?

No, its the TCP, sorry for the confusion. I am unsure whether the source was from the book by sir clayden, because I have the south asia edition only. I shall update soon

Got it! https://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p0121

Oh, I found that "Consequently, a structurally specific alkylation of an enolate anion can be successful only if the alkylation reaction is more rapid than equilibration so that the starting enolate 2 is consumed by the alkylating agent before significant amounts of the unwanted enolate 1 have been formed". 1 for TC enolate and 2 is for KC enolate.

You left out an important part of the reaction  conditions --namely -- 0.95 equivalents of LDA. The authors in your reference presumed that the kinetic enolate is formed. They allowed equilibration to occur through the 0.05 equivalents of 2-methylcyclopentanone that was not deprotonated. To facilitate enolate exchange, they allowed the  rxn. mixture to warm to room temperature prior to alkylation.

When I go through comments sections, I see there are a lot of confusions about how the reaction proceed through mechanistically. There are a few points you need to know about this reaction, which are overlooked by the readers. The reaction conditions are specifically $\pu{0.95 equiv.}$ of lithium diisopropyl amide (LDA) with respective to the ketone starting material in THF at $\pu{-78 ^\circ C}$. This theoretically gives you $\pu{0.95 equiv.}$ of kinetic enolate and $\pu{0.05 equiv.}$ of free ketone, the presence of which must need to facilitate the initial enolate to slowly equilibrate (it takes about $4$-$\pu{5 h}$) to thermodynamically more stable enolate anion at room temperature (Ref. 1). In practice, when  quenching this thermodynamically stable enolate with 2,3-dibromopropene at $\pu{0 ^\circ C}$, it gives chromatographically pure $79\%$ yield of the product (Ref. 2). Note that allyl bromide reagent has added at the end of reaction time, not as indicated in the scheme provided by the OP.
The detailed equilibrium process has given in Ref. 1 as follows:


References:

Herbert O. House and Barry M. Trost, "The Chemistry of Carbanions. IX. The Potassium and Lithium Enolates Derived from Cyclic Ketones," J. Org. Chem. 1965, 30(5), 1341–1348 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01016a001).
Steven C. Welch and Suthep Chayabunjonglerd, "A stereoselective total synthesis of ($\pm$)-gymnomitrol," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1979, 101(22), 6768–6769 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00516a057).


I believe I had made this very point in the Comments. BTW: Although House was know for his meticulousness, I have always doubted that the dianion (structure 3) be can be formed from triphenylmethyl potassium or lithium. Triphenylmethane has a pKa of 33. Even if there is localized charge on oxygen, the formation of an allyl anion (propene pKa= ~42) is questionable. An upvote.

@user55119 : Yes you have made exact point (I didn't see it before because I have concentration on confusion among readers' comments).  As a matter of fact, House and Trost have used triphenylmethyl lithium (and potassium) in their research (Ref. 1) as you pointed.

On another issue. What software you. use to format references?

I didn't use software. Did it old Pasion way, Just typed in. :-)

The enolate oxygen is a sufficiently strong proton acceptor to form a five-membered hydrogen-bonded ring with the methyl group, an example of molecular-orbital structure allowing an "unconventional" hydrogen bond. Hydrogen atoms directly attached to the carbon ring would not be suitably positioned for this extra delocalization.


The explanation merely describes how the more thermodynamically favored enolate forms in this case, However, the mentioned "extra delocalization" does not permanently applied to all cases, is it not?

It would not universally apply. You need the properly positioned hydrogens for this interaction to work.

So, for 2-methylcyclohexanone, is there any method that could ensure the formation of kinetically controlled enolate?

@CuckooBeats is there any reference in particular?

@Shira umm it is in my class notes, I shall first clarify the source and then post further here, thanks. For now ChemLibreTexts has briefly gone over this

I have just realised the reason that kinetically enolate is not formed. It is because the reaction proceeds at room temperature. It is not contradict anyway
